# Why isnt my class update function updating my variable

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random, pygame


#window setup aswell as global variable
pygame.init()
screen_size = 400
global window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size,screen_size))
pygame.display.set_caption("evolution simulator")

pygame.display.update()
def draw_Grid():
    global Grid
    Grid = [[]]
    blockSize = 20
    for x in range(0,20):
        for y in range(0,20):
            Grid.append(1)
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blockSize, y*blockSize,blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,0), rect, 1)
##draw_Grid()
##pygame.display.update()
class spurgs:
    def __init__(self,age,hunger,speed,gender):
        # 1 for male, 2 for female
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.speed = speed
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
    def update(self):
        #growing up
```

> Here I am setting the variable it should be working but it isnt ??!?

```
self.age = self.age + 1
        self.hunger -= 1
        if self.age > 10:
            self.speed += 1
        elif self.age >50:
            self.speed -= 1
    def eat(self):
        self.hunger +=1
        #remove some food  to affect global food resource
    def breed(self,mate):
        if mate.gender != self.gender:
            baby_gender = random.randint(1,2)
            baby = spugs(1,100,20,baby_gender)
    def draw(self,color,grid_coord_X,grid_coord_Y,size):
        pygame.draw.circle(window,color,(grid_coord_X,grid_coord_Y),size)
run = True  
while run:
    window.fill((0,200,255))
    draw_Grid()
    #QUIT CONDITION
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("closing the loop")
            run = False
    test_spurg = spurgs(10,100,1,2)
    test_spurg.draw((0,255,20),20,20,5)
    test_spurg.update()
    print(test_spurg.age)
```

> Here I use the update function in a while loop it should change the age on every iteration i.e infintely

```
pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

> If there are any other syntax errors or I'm just not adhering to some common rule, feel free to point it out !

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating a new object in every iteration.

I think you need to create a new object only once and use that in the `while` loop as:

```
window.fill((0,200,255))
draw_Grid()
test_spurg = spurgs(10,100,1,2)
test_spurg.draw((0,255,20),20,20,5)
while run:
    #QUIT CONDITION
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("closing the loop")
            run = False
    test_spurg.update()
    print(test_spurg.age)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the value of the attribute is changed, but since you create a new object every frame, it will continuously start with the initial value.

You need to create the instance of the object before the application loop, but you need to draw the scene in the application loop:

```py
# create objects
test_spurg = spurgs(10,100,1,2)

run = True  
while run:
    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("closing the loop")
            run = False
    
    # update objects
    test_spurg.update()
    print(test_spurg.age)

    # draw scene
    window.fill((0,200,255))
    draw_Grid()
    test_spurg.draw((0,255,20),20,20,5)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The objects are created before the application loop. In the application loop, the attributes of the object, e.g. B. its position is continuously changed and the scene is redrawn to reflect the changes. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)